# ARC option enabled not fixing memory leak

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, xcode4.3

My project does support ARC:

[image]

But when i run the Xcode Analyzer, Product/Analyze, i still get memory leak such:

```
Potential leak of an object allocated on line xx and stored into 'xxx'.
```

I mean, isn't the ARC supposed to fix suck release issues? or i have to add the release/autorelease by myself?

Comment: Please post your code as text rather than as an image.

Comment: Are you using the 'new lifetime qualifiers' such as 'strong' and 'weak'?

Comment: (And are you sure you have ARC enabled?)

Comment: @Hot Liks: I am not checking ARC from when i created my project, but now i am enabling it from the project settings. ISn't enough to support retain/release ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your files don't have -fno-objc-arc in linker flags. This excludes them from ARC. An easy way to check is to try releasing an object in your code, if you get a red line through the release call then the file is using ARC, xcode won't let you have any release calls in a file with ARC enabled.

Comment: Hi, Thanx a lot for your clarifications, actually, i tried release an object but i don't get any error, this is making things confusing to me.